# C++ Merge 2 Strings Together

Tags: c++, string, access-denied

I'm trying to create a simple text file to Desktop, but I get in the console : "**Access is denied.**". I do the same thing from the Comand Line and no error. If I where to print the *path* I would get :
"

C:/Users/Alex
(Here is a new line)
/Desktop/MyTextFile.txt

I know when I add a string to another string via **+=** *string*, I get a space between the 2 strings. Any help would be apreciate !

```
string getClip() {
    HANDLE clip;
    string clip_text = "";
    if (OpenClipboard(NULL))
    {
        clip = GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);
        clip_text = (char*)clip;
        CloseClipboard();
        return clip_text;
    }
}
string getUser() {
    system("echo %username% | clip");
    string user = getClip();
    return user;
}
void create_a_simple_txt_file() {
    string username = getUser();

    ostringstream path;
    path << "C:/Users/" << username << "/Desktop/MyTextFile.txt";
    system(("echo I successful Write something to my file > " + path.str()).c_str());

}

int main() {
    create_a_simple_txt_file();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post `getUser()` code

Comment: That message is coming from Windows. The username is probably one you don't have rights to unless you're logged in as that user.

Comment: @Rama If you use this code, do you still get an error, like **Acces Deniel** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the usage of `system` and the `echo` command:

```
system("echo %username% | clip");
```

The `echo` command *adds* a trailing newline, which is copied into the clipboard with the `clip` command, and you then get the full string including the newline with `getClip`.

You could simply fix this by not using `system` at all, and instead get the username with the [`GetUserName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724432(v=vs.85).aspx) Windows API function:

```
std::string getUser()
{
    char username[64];

    // Use the ASCII version of the function
    if (GetUserNameA(username, sizeof username))
    {
        return username;
    }

    // An error
    std::cerr << "Error getting username: " << GetLastError() << '\n';
    return "";
}
```

Comment: I found a better solution. I could use ** echo|set /p=%Username%** to print without a new line.

Comment: @AlexM. Why do you insist on using `system` and external commands? There's simply no need for it?

Comment: @AlexM.: "Better" is quite debatable there.

Answer (score 1):

I would bet your problem is in the `getUser()` function, that is returning the username with a trailing newline, not the string concatenation (that, by the way, does NOT add a space).

*EDITED after question being edited:*
As I supposed, the problem is in your getUser() function, see "Some programmer dude" answer about why it is wrong and a possible solution, if you are running on Windows OS.

Another problem can be that you are trying to access the desktop folder of another user, and the user running your program does not have permissions on it.

Another suggestion: you may want to use the appropriate C++ functions or fstream to write to a file, instead of using `system()`.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an **access denied** error because you are working on garbage data. The line

```
system(("echo I successful Write something to my file > " + path.str()).c_str());
```

creates a temporary string and gets a pointer to its underlying character array. But before the `system()` call is executed, the temporary string gets destroyed and the pointer becomes invalid.

If you replace your system call with a `cout` you can see what command you are actually trying to execute. For me it was something like `Ó╣iwµ`, which is neither a valid command not a valid directory name. Hence, the **access denied**.

To solve that problem, assign the temporary string to a variable until you have used it:

```
string s = ("echo I successful Write something to my file > " + path.str());
system(s.c_str());
```